# Path (URL) to call custom module function

Tags: 7, path-aliases, uri

I am developing a custom module and I need an URL that would trigger an action when called.

The purpose is for an external server to call this address passing some variables through `$_REQUEST['message']`, and then return a STRING with the success/error string. So the URL in question is only supposed to be called by a machine.

I now have a PHP file in the root that does the job, but I'd like to integrate it to the Drupal way through this custom module.... Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do this is to build a custom module and implement the hook hook_menu().

You'll need to implement:

- a .info file with metadata about your
  module
- a .module file containing
  hook_menu() and your callback

foo.module should look like this:

```
function foo_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['foo/myurl'] = array( // change 'foo/myurl' to the url you want
    'title' => 'Callback',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'custom_callback',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}

function custom_callback () {
  // Parse $_REQUEST parameters
  return 'success';
}
```

Comment: how can I make the `custom_callback()` function to `echo` some when visited from the browser? It should return a string (or an XML)...

Comment: Using echo() :)

Comment: maybe you can guide me on this one? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/6667/1146 (continuation of this one, but I'd rather make it a Question than a comment). Thanks