# How to prevent displaying the theme on a custom page callback in hook_menu()

Tags: hooks, theming

I am developing a custom module with a callback script at `foo/myurl`:

```
function foo_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['foo/myurl'] = array( // change 'foo/myurl' to the url you want
    'title' => 'Callback',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'custom_callback',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}

function custom_callback () {
  echo 'success';
  return;
}
```

But this URL is to be called by a 3rd party script, and I only want to return the `echo`ed string, how can I prevent the rest of the theme from loading?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply don't return any value, and exit.

In Drupal 7, that can be done by calling [drupal_exit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_exit/7). In Drupal 6, you use code similar to the following one:

```
function custom_callback() {
  echo 'success';
  module_invoke_all('exit');
  exit();
}
```

When you call `drupal_exit()` you don't need to use `exit` too, as it is already used by the function.

`exit()` (or `drupal_exit()`) avoids other hooks are invoked after `hook_exit()`.
Drupal normally calls `drupal_page_footer()` after the menu callback returns its value; using `exit()` (or `drupal_exit()`) avoids that function is called, too. The effect is that the output of the menu callback is not cached. If caching the output is desired then the call to `module_invoke_all('exit')` and `exit()`, or `drupal_exit()` can be removed. As far as the menu callback doesn't return any value, the Drupal page will not be rendered, as it is evident in the Drupal 6 code contained in the index.php file:

```
$return = menu_execute_active_handler();

// Menu status constants are integers; page content is a string.
if (is_int($return)) {
  switch ($return) {
    case MENU_NOT_FOUND:
      drupal_not_found();
      break;
    case MENU_ACCESS_DENIED:
      drupal_access_denied();
      break;
    case MENU_SITE_OFFLINE:
      drupal_site_offline();
      break;
  }
}
elseif (isset($return)) {
  // Print any value (including an empty string) except NULL or undefined:
  print theme('page', $return);
}

drupal_page_footer();
```

Comment: exit() is not necessary. Just don't return anything and Drupal does not print anything additional.

Comment: yeah, but drupal_page_footer() is nothing more than saving the page cache and hook_exit(). There is more in Drupal 7, but nothing that you might want to prevent (like saving session changes and various cache writes.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `delivery callback` property of your menu entry to specify the function to be used to *render* the results of your `page callback`. The default delivery callback is [`drupal_deliver_html_page`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_deliver_html_page/7). The page handler for the AJAX callback page at `system/ajax` uses [`ajax_deliver`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--ajax.inc/function/ajax_deliver/7) to return a JSON data.

This allow you to properly separate the page logic (ie. getting to data to output) from the rendering (ie. formatting the data).

Comment: that is a very thoughtful detail, thank you for pointing it out!