# Page not found when trying to access custom module

Tags: 7

I've followed this post and made a custom module but when I try to access it from url domain.com/module/method I get 404?

Am I missing something?

[Path (URL) to call custom module function](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6621/path-url-to-call-custom-module-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So much could be going wrong from a finger fudge standpoint here, so just make sure you have something very similar to this going on:

For example, in quick.info:

```
name = quick module
core = 6.x
description = quick module
package = quick package
```

In quick.module:

```
<?php

function quick_menu() {

  $items = array();
  $items['quick/hello'] = array( // change to the url you want
    'title' => 'Quick Hello',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page callback' => 'quick_hello',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );

  return $items;
}

function quick_hello() {

  $content='Hello. Thank you for surfing over to ' . $_GET['q'];
  return $content;
}
```

Obviously make sure your module is enabled and not so obviously that all caches are cleared, but past that, the most important piece of the above is the 'quick/hello' when it comes to page found/not found :)

Comment: Thnx it was the caches.....